# How to run CANoe testmodule via Python?

Tags: python, xml, capl, canoe

I would like to be able to start a testmodule that is in my CANoe script; it works fine if I start everything without Python.

Now, my Python code can load CANoe, open the desired cfg, and start the simulation.
I tried some code from examples in the documentation and here, but it doesnt work...

```python
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Standard library imports
import os
import sys
import subprocess
# import win32com.client
import time
import threading
from win32com.client import *
from win32com.client.connect import *

my_xml_ts = r"C:\_my_path\boaz_test2.xml"

# Vector Canoe Class
class CANoe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.application = None
        # check if there is any instance of CANoe process
        # output = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
        # if CANoe process is still available, kill the process
        # if "CANoe32.exe" in str(output):
        #     os.system("taskkill /im CANoe32.exe /f 2>nul >nul")

        # re-dispatch object for CANoe Application
        self.application = win32com.client.DispatchEx("CANoe.Application")
        self.ver = self.application.Version
        print('Loaded CANoe version ',
            self.ver.major, '.',
            self.ver.minor, '.',
            self.ver.Build, '...')#, sep,''

        self.Measurement = self.application.Measurement.Running
        print(self.Measurement)


    def open_simulation(self, cfgname):
        # open CANoe simulation
        if (self.application != None):
            # check for valid file and it is *.cfg file
            if os.path.isfile(cfgname) and (os.path.splitext(cfgname)[1] == ".cfg"):
                self.application.Open(cfgname)
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Can't find CANoe cfg file")
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("CANoe Application is missing,unable to open simulation")

    def set_testmodule(self):
        print("set_testmodule start")
        test_env = self.application.Configuration.TestSetup.TestEnvironments.Item("Test Environment")
        print("set_testmodule 1")
        test_env = win32com.client.CastTo(test_env, "ITestEnvironment2")
        print("set_testmodule 2")
        self.test_module = test_env.TestModules.Item("XML_Boaz_2")
        print("set_testmodule end", self.test_module)

    def test_module_run(self):
        print("test_module_run start")
        self.test_module.Start()
        print("test_module_run end")

        #     {.Sequence} property returns a collection of <TestCases> or <TestGroup>
        # or <TestSequenceItem> which is more generic
        seq = self.test_module.Sequence
        for i in range(1, seq.Count + 1):
            # Cast from <ITestSequenceItem> to <ITestCase> to access {.Verdict}
            # and the {.Enabled} property
            tc = win32com.client.CastTo(seq.Item(i), "ITestCase")
            if tc.Verdict != 1:  # Verdict 1 is pass
                tc.Enabled = True
                print(f"Enabling Test Case {tc.Ident} with verdict {tc.Verdict}")
            else:
                tc.Enabled = False
                print(f"Disabling Test Case {tc.Ident} since it has already passed")

    def close_simulation(self):
        # close CANoe simulation
        if (self.application != None):
            self.stop_Measurement()
            self.application.Quit()

        # make sure the CANoe is close properly, otherwise enforce taskkill
        output = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)

        if "CANoe32.exe" in str(output):
            os.system("taskkill /im CANoe32.exe /f 2>nul >nul")

        self.application = None

    def start_Measurement(self):
        retry = 0
        retry_counter = 5
        # try to establish measurement within 20s timeout
        while not self.application.Measurement.Running and (retry < retry_counter):
            self.application.Measurement.Start()
            time.sleep(1)
            retry += 1
        if (retry == retry_counter):
            raise RuntimeWarning("CANoe start measuremet failed, Please Check Connection!")
```

and running that:

```
import Python_CANoe
import time
import random

def try2():

    X = random.randrange(50)
    Y = random.randrange(100)
    print("start")

    CANoe = Python_CANoe.CANoe()


    CANoe.open_simulation(canoe_config_file)
    CANoe.set_testmodule()                    # Doesn't work

    print("CANoe script already Open")

    CANoe.start_Measurement()
    time.sleep(5)
    CANoe.test_module_run()                       # Doesn't work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try2()
```

and this is the error code I am getting:

```
set_testmodule start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/m.m/Documents/Python/CANoe_Python_Script/7_5_2021_3_for_stackoverflow/CANoe_Boaz_Test.py", line 133, in <module>
    try2()
  File "C:/Users/m.m/Documents/Python/CANoe_Python_Script/7_5_2021_3_for_stackoverflow/CANoe_Boaz_Test.py", line 77, in try2
CANoe.set_testmodule()                    # Doesn't work
  File "C:\Users\m.m\Documents\Python\CANoe_Python_Script\7_5_2021_3_for_stackoverflow\Python_CANoe.py", line 52, in set_testmodule
test_env = self.application.Configuration.TestSetup.TestEnvironments.Item("Test Environment")
  File "C:\Users\BOAZ~1.BIL\LOCALS~1\Temp\gen_py\3.7\7F31DEB0-5BCC-11D3-8562-00105A3E017Bx0x1x58.py", line 15873, in Item
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'TestEnvironments::Item', 'Invalid index: Item not found!', 'C:\\Program Files\\Vector CANoe 11.0\\Help01\\CANoeCANalyzer.chm', 4281, -2147467259), None)
```

Comment: As the  error message tells you, you do not have an test-environment that is called `Test Environment`

Comment: Thanks M. Spiller! I wonder where do I find it? Is that even necessary (I couldn't find examples that dont use that line; I thought  'Test Environment' is generic.
My CANoe and test-module script works manually. 
is that something that can be skipped, or how can I find it? Thanks

Comment: This line `self.application.Configuration.TestSetup.TestEnvironments.Item("Test Environment")` tries to get access to a test environment called `Test Environment`. In case your test environment is called differently, you should use a different identifier obviously. All this is clearly documented in CANoe's documentation. Without anybody but you knowing the details about your CANoe setup, nobody can help you.

Comment: I do have that file 'Test Environment.tse', and I copied it to where my CANoe script is located (also copied to where the .py script is), but still get the same error.

Comment: You should not copy around files. The files does not matter while executing the Python script, nor does the filename. The test environment hast to exits in CANoe. Open the test setup in CANoe, search for the test environment of interest, not its name and use that very name in your Python script

Comment: M. Spiller, thank you very much, your notes were helpful, and I was able to make it! 
I really didn't know about the need to run the xml tests batch via tse (no need for that tse when running everything manually...). I did short investigation and found out how to set tse to call an xml (or .can CAPL code) and run it.
Thanks!